# Piwik Analytics solution for extjs single page application

Tags: angularjs, extjs4, analytics, single-page-application, matomo

I have a Single Page web application which just has index.html as the entry page for application, all other URLs and screens load based on extjs scripts.

I added the Javascript tracker code before  tag and am able to track whenever a user logs in via index.html page. Howerver, there are multiple screens with different URLs in my application, not sure how can we track other screens(different URLs loaded at runtime) via Piwik

I saw some solution for Angular JS single page application, do we have something similar for extjs as well?

Please post any related information and with those pointers, probably we can reach a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no official guide about this but [it is planned](https://github.com/piwik/developer-documentation/issues/90).

In order to track the different screens, you will need to push manually page views to Piwik. First you can have a look at the guide for [the JavaScript Tracking Client](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide).

Here is an example to push a page view:

```
// Piwik must be loaded normally above

// Track a page change
_paq.push(['setCustomUrl', newUrl);
_paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.title]);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

You could also [track events](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#manually-trigger-events) if some links are more "actions" than pages.

You can also have a look at all the features and options in the [JavaScript Tracking Client API reference](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript).